# How can I make a variable-length menu that extends to the bottom of the screen with padding using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So here's the situation: I have a menu that has some amount of fixed-length content followed by an amount of variable-length scrollable content. I want to make the variable length section have a max-height that extends to the bottom of the screen minus *x* amount of padding. To give a visual example:

```
-----
Menu bar  - 40px
-----
* x px padding
*
| 32px top content
*
*
|
|
| ?px - variable length
|
|
*                        
* x px - padding
```

The HTML structure is something like this:

```
<div class="menu-bar">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-button"></div>
    <div class="menu-content">
      <div class="header-content"></div>
      <div class="variable-length-content"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main-document">
  ...
</div>
```

The menu itself is a child of the menu bar, but it is absolutely positioned into the document body with a top that is the menu bar height + the padding amount.

What's the best way to do this? I could probably do it with Javascript, but I'm wondering if there's a CSS-only way.

Comment: "variable-length" How are you going to set the length?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - It depends upon the number of items in the menu. In most cases, the number of items will exceed the max-height, requiring scrolling. But there is a filter, so the menu can shrink to be smaller than the max height.

Comment: So basically you want a menu that its max height is the height of the window, and if the content inside the menu has only a few items, then it can shrink back to not being 100% of the window's height?

Comment: What is your HTML structure ? Cause this is what will tell wich CSS method can be applied. ( there is many CSS ways to achieve such a template ... )

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Lresrkqc/1/ Can't get bottom padding, though... Ah, it is in container, well...

Comment: @GCyrillus - Does that help?

Comment: i guess it helps you, here my idea about the flex possibilitie for young browsers. http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/EVYvow

Comment: display:table ? possibilitie ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mebMxv for the calc() or absolute positionning, there is answers below ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you're looking for, does this might help?

```
.content {
  /* Subtract the header size */
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

more here: https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use CSS3 you can use "vh" units for the view height. Combined with calc to subtract your fixed padding size.

```
.variable-content {
    height:-webkit-calc(100vh - 300px)
}
```

Check this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Loqy7yfr/

Comment: if CSS3, then flex would be the most efficient and easy way to do it ;)

Comment: from the html provided by the op, here is the idea about flex :) http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/EVYvow

Answer (score 0):

So many different scenarios with possible solutions differing based on your html structure and other specific needs, here's a ***very rough*** sample:

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/1f7hbgp6/4/

CSS:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.menu-1 {
    position: absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:200px;
}
.menu-1 > ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom:0px;
    padding-bottom: 70px; /* any padding */
    border:1px solid #0ff;
}
.menu-1 > ul > li {
    display: block;
}
.menu-1 > ul > li:first-child {
    height:32px;
}
.menu-1 > ul > li:nth-child(2) {
    overflow-y:auto;
    max-height:calc(100% - 32px);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="menu-1">
    <ul>
        <li>32px top content</li>
        <li>? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length ? px - variable length</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code if it helps...

Here is the code that i wrote based on your requirement ..

[Click Me](https://jsfiddle.net/a6y2692f/)

## HTML

```
  <div id="wrap">
    <div class="header">
        Head/Title
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        Content goes here
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        Footer
    </div>
```

## CSS

```
            #wrap{
                width:100%;
                height:400px;
                background-color:pink;
            }
            .header{
                height:5%;
                background-color:yellow;
                text-align:center;
            }
            .content{
                height:100%;
                background-color:lightblue;
                width:100%;
            }
            .footer{
                height:20px;
                background-color:grey;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `calc` to simplify all the calculations needed:

```
calc(100vh - 50px);
```

and here is a quick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/h2q4u0us/

[image]

Some browsers may require vendor prefixes, such as

```
-webkit-calc  for Webkit
-moz-calc     for Firefox
```

All major browsers support `calc` at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without the use of `calc` even if it may be widely supported, there is actually no need to use it in this situation. Sure it can make your life easier, but if you just know the `height` of a few elements you can use padding and positioning to make that work.

Hope this helps.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
  margin:0;
}
.menu-bar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  min-height: 40px;
}
.menu-bar nav {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  padding: 40px 0 25px; /* top padding height of .menu-bar and bottom-padding */
  background: gray;
  z-index: -1;
}
.menu-bar .navbar {
  width: 200px;
  height: inherit;
  padding-bottom: 32px; /* remove the height of .top-content from the bottom */
}
.menu-bar .top-content {
  width: inherit;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: red;
}
.menu-bar .variable-content {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-bar">
  <nav>
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="top-content"></div>
      <ul class="variable-content">
        <li>item 1</li><li>item 2</li><li>item 3</li>
        <li>item 4</li><li>item 5</li><li>item 6</li>
        <li>item 7</li><li>item 8</li><li>item 9</li>
        <li>item 10</li><li>item 11</li><li>item 12</li>
        <li>item 13</li><li>item 14</li><li>item 15</li>
        <li>item 16</li><li>item 17</li><li>item 18</li>
        <li>item 19</li><li>item 20</li><li>item 21</li>
        <li>item 22</li><li>item 23</li><li>item 24</li>
        <li>item 25</li><li>item 26</li><li>item 27</li>
        <li>item 28</li><li>item 29</li><li>item 30</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try that in fiddle or your own html.

Variable height for a div only with CSS.

```
body,html,.bodyDiv{
    height:100%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

.content{
    background:#000;
}

.topSpacing{
    background:#fefefe;
    height:35px;
}

.bottomSpacing{
    background:#fefefe;
    height:35px;     
}

.table {
    display:table;
    border:0px solid #000;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    height:100%;
}

.row {
    display:table-row;
}

.cell {
    display:table-cell;
    padding:0px;
    border:0px solid #000;
}    

<div class="table">
    <!-- topSpacing -->
    <div class="row topSpacing">
        <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- bottomSpacing -->
    <div class="row content">
        <div class="cell">Conten</div>
    </div>
    <!-- bottomSpacing -->
    <div class="row bottomSpacing">
        <div class="cell"></div>

    </div>
</div>
```